# Why is my Python palindrome-function failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, while-loop, palindrome

```
def is_palindrome(input_string):
# We'll create two strings, to compare them
   if input_string[0:] == input_string[-1:]:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

**expected output is below:**

`print(is_palindrome("Never Odd or Even")) # Should be True
print(is_palindrome("abc")) # Should be False
print(is_palindrome("kayak")) # Should be True`

I am currently getting False for all cases. I know my splicing might be off on the -1. I already tried swapping the colon around to no avail.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  First, research the topic.  Second, trace your own program's values.  Either of these would have immediately shown your error.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it now, you're comparing all the letters to the last letter.

```py
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a[-1:]
[3]
>>> a[0:]
[1,2,3]
```

But that's not how you reverse a string, or any iterable.  The step index should be negative:

```py
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a[::-1]
[3,2,1]
```

So you just want to compare the original string to that

Comment: Thank you!. I guess I need to brush up on splicing indeed. This helped me get the last two test cases to pass.I think the first one is failing due to the spaces. I think I have to use the .join() method somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you want to remove the spaces beforehand and lower or upper the letters.

```
l = ['Never Odd or Even', 'abc', 'kayak']

def isit(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', '').lower()
    return s == s[::-1]

for e in l:
    isit(e)


True
False
True
```